# Can we merge [falcon9-r] into [falcon-9]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There's currently both a [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) and a [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) tag. As far as I can see, [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) is the generic tag for the Falcon 9 rocket, and [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) is specifically for the reusable version (and was originally meant for Falcons with a reusable first *and* second stage, which never happened). But apart from the first five Falcon 9 v1.0 rockets, all Falcon 9's have been reusable.

[falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) has 414 questions, and [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) has 59. Of those 59, 36 are also tagged with [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9). Therefore, I propose to merge [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) into [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9).

Comment: I support this idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've made the change, the tags are one.

Comment: And yet the two tags still seem separate. Maybe we can keep them separate and instead just get the falcon9-r tag on the questions where it really belongs? Or perhaps there never was such a thing? To get to the bottom of the appropriateness and utilityof having two tags I've just asked [How to determine on which questions the falcon9-r and falcon-9 tags do and don't belong?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2840/12102)

Comment: @uhoh It looks like at the time Pearson accidentally merged [tag:falcon-9r] instead of [tag:falcon9-r] into [tag:falcon-9].

Comment: @called2voyage oh I'm not surprised, I can't even tell/see the difference, thanks! (then again, my brain probably [looks like this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/103059/27918))