# How to determine on which questions the falcon9-r and falcon-9 tags do and don't belong?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging, retagging

**note:** I'm perplexed by the answer to [Can we merge [falcon9-r] into [falcon-9]?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1295/12102) since there still seems to be two different tags with different question counts!

---

There are [currently 36 questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r+falcon-9) tagged with both [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) (**575** questions) and [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) (**58** questions).

I have a hunch that several times both were added out of a sense of "inclusiveness" rather than the questions really being about "Falcon 9R" and/or "Falcon 9".

Before the scope of any potential retagging effort can be estimated, it's necessary to have a good understanding of the relationship between and extent of actual overlap of these two tags.

**Question:** How to determine on which questions the falcon9-r and falcon9 tags do and don't belong?

Here are some examples that could be examined, sorted chronologically:

- [Was there a barge landing attempt on Launch 16 (EUTELSAT 115 / ABS 3A) March 1st](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8378/12102)
- [Does the Falcon 9 (v1.1) first stage have an explosive Flight Termination System?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8762/12102)
- [How does the Falcon 9 know where the landing barge/pad is?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8779/12102)
- [Why did the RCS thrusters on Falcon 9 fire in the wrong direction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8804/12102)
- [Did CRS-6 landing fail because the steering fins are ineffective at low speed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8817/12102)
- [How far from launchpad did Falcon 9's first stage go?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13178/12102) (I’ve removed falcon9-r to make room)
- [Is it possible the Falcon Heavy Demo flight could be done with three previously flown boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13185/12102)
- [What is the burn time for the F9 boostback / reentry / landing burns?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13700/12102)
- [How does the Falcon 9 first stage avoid burning up on re-entry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13935/12102)
- [What are the version number and identification names for each Falcon 9-r boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15166/12102)
- [What are the two bright objects separating from the Falcon 9?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20002/12102)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with a question having [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) and [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) tags, even if it's only about [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r). Falcon 9R is just a special configuration of Falcon     9, so the [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) tag still applies. The only reason someone should drop the more general tag is if they need the space for other tags.

That said, if someone applied [falcon9-r](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) to a question that is *not* about the Falcon 9R, by mistake, then that tag should be removed.

Comment: Being ever-confused on the namings of things and wondering about how well the tag has actually been applied, I've just asked in the main site [Which Falcon-9 launches were of a Falcon-9R rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54550/12102)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `falcon-9r` tag description says "variant of the SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket with reusable first **and second stages**" I suggest we remove it entirely, folding any misuse of it into `falcon-9`, since no such animal exists.

Comment: If there are valid questions posted about the variant (which has been at least talked about) then shouldn't those questions keep this tag? We have plenty of questions about rockets that were proposed but never existed.

Comment: Not everything needs its own tag.

Comment: But this question is not about "everything", it's about a group of questions that have been posted on the site, so we should speak about whether the site is improved if their tag is revoked or not.

Comment: And my position is that the site will be improved by the merging of the tags, as was the consensus when the same question was discussed two years ago. Each of your example questions, at title glance, seem to refer to extant Falconidae.

Comment: I see, [How does SpaceX plan to achieve reusability of the Falcon 9 *second* stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10391/12102) doesn't have the tag, nor does [What are the challenges in recovering Falcon 9's second stage this way?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44582/12102).  I agree it's not a useful nor helpful tag. "Make it so!"

Comment: Merge and synonymization complete!